# How do I convert a single array from nested arrays into dataframe rows?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I would like to convert below nested arrays into DataFrame. Specifically, I want to convert each arrays in the nested arrays as data frame rows. There are altogether 24 nested arrays but I just copied few of those to not make the post any longer

For example from the below array, I want to convert a single array into one row in DataFrame. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
[array([[[-1.36013642e-01,  1.59766637e-02,  4.49674837e-02,
           2.87157446e-02, -9.56720412e-02, -8.88903514e-02,
          -5.33084199e-02, -2.13210974e-02,  1.41174316e-01,
          -4.11187410e-02,  1.70307457e-01, -2.14784797e-02,
          -1.35124326e-01, -1.13939375e-01, -3.31919976e-02,
           6.11963794e-02, -1.17217958e-01, -1.50817335e-01,
          -4.65203971e-02, -1.00571744e-01,  7.85203278e-02,
           2.94833463e-02,  1.02086905e-02,  1.93061940e-02,
          -2.32153490e-01, -3.00551683e-01, -1.17443979e-01,
          -1.46142572e-01,  1.07608363e-01, -9.40902233e-02,
          -3.90545353e-02,  4.42864373e-02, -1.29430681e-01,
          -7.02960119e-02,  8.21319446e-02,  1.80883124e-01,
          -2.02056542e-02, -2.47046854e-02,  1.82081938e-01,
           3.43354326e-03, -1.19226977e-01, -5.64751402e-03,
           5.98295629e-02,  3.01894635e-01,  1.70621589e-01,
           1.36449412e-01,  4.88062464e-02, -4.68050130e-02,
           1.07072420e-01, -2.24809378e-01,  1.33529887e-01,
           1.69836447e-01,  1.21353425e-01,  3.47930416e-02,
           2.27185443e-01, -2.41639778e-01,  3.87575626e-02,
           1.36878729e-01, -1.31427586e-01,  1.35682166e-01,
          -8.80223699e-04,  1.59485396e-02,  2.62592174e-02,
          -3.75868753e-02,  1.91311508e-01,  6.34296760e-02,
          -6.77121654e-02, -9.76699442e-02,  1.88637391e-01,
          -1.95635721e-01,  2.61483667e-03,  1.27198607e-01,
          -7.48684406e-02, -1.59019291e-01, -2.47020170e-01,
          -3.68376747e-02,  4.33871210e-01,  1.57070860e-01,
          -1.62113741e-01,  3.82730290e-02, -3.92096601e-02,
          -4.57221121e-02,  9.67647210e-02, -6.17119949e-05,
          -1.43869311e-01, -6.41668867e-03, -1.91071168e-01,
          -2.21797563e-02,  2.02202812e-01,  3.91443223e-02,
           4.61347327e-02,  1.54131114e-01,  7.47928210e-03,
           2.09267866e-02,  3.87379229e-02, -5.46494387e-02,
          -1.59527451e-01,  7.56314816e-03, -2.13688631e-02,
          -5.44707663e-02,  6.98875338e-02, -1.67583689e-01,
          -1.69844925e-03,  9.92566273e-02, -1.98496655e-01,
           6.26156628e-02, -2.95266993e-02,  5.99580631e-03,
          -6.91434443e-02,  3.17127258e-02, -1.32520899e-01,
           2.55816411e-02,  1.90661669e-01, -2.88114160e-01,
           1.65751979e-01,  1.89788476e-01, -3.19299102e-02,
           1.52912185e-01,  8.25165361e-02,  6.92607239e-02,
          -2.91225202e-02, -3.67325470e-02, -1.58863515e-01,
          -4.12161574e-02, -9.37818438e-02, -1.08723141e-01,
           1.27439285e-02,  7.31237382e-02]],
 
        [[-1.37894586e-01,  5.84010258e-02,  9.80348736e-02,
          -9.55949910e-03, -6.22733906e-02, -5.63683398e-02,
          -2.26371922e-02, -8.96835402e-02,  1.46475613e-01,
          -4.40802239e-02,  1.53038278e-01, -3.29063646e-03,
          -1.69211119e-01, -1.14617534e-01,  5.59688732e-03,
           5.93355000e-02, -1.27704740e-01, -1.71358287e-01,
          -4.84642014e-02, -8.19769055e-02,  2.84060407e-02,
           6.13150261e-02, -7.79468417e-02, -8.77461210e-03,
          -2.00844258e-01, -2.88251281e-01, -7.33745247e-02,
          -1.42669410e-01,  1.07440352e-01, -1.39590308e-01,
          -3.51556130e-02, -4.18033963e-03, -1.82463229e-01,
          -4.28252965e-02,  5.28394952e-02,  1.75120696e-01,
          -9.33501031e-03, -3.33592743e-02,  1.65851176e-01,
           1.39791211e-02, -1.52489260e-01, -6.68389164e-03,
           5.71185611e-02,  2.38399506e-01,  1.53594971e-01,
           7.59008080e-02,  1.48483068e-02, -5.43878600e-02,
           1.36847854e-01, -1.76150039e-01,  1.25447407e-01,
           1.70887619e-01,  1.22895576e-01,  5.84644414e-02,
           1.99920326e-01, -2.79710770e-01,  1.56115033e-02,
           5.12041822e-02, -1.93132162e-01,  1.51428387e-01,
           5.97179160e-02, -1.93341300e-02, -4.03094850e-03,
           1.73912272e-02,  1.02863029e-01, -4.60668234e-03,
          -6.12722374e-02, -1.03243664e-01,  1.96056634e-01,
          -1.93443596e-01,  2.90273000e-02,  9.11512822e-02,
          -3.45249921e-02, -1.79792568e-01, -2.18977749e-01,
           2.92301551e-02,  3.94104689e-01,  1.66036054e-01,
          -2.10731253e-01,  4.83864099e-02, -4.31987755e-02,
          -9.82125998e-02,  1.06999256e-01,  1.90159921e-02,
          -5.58431894e-02,  3.04446071e-02, -1.47668719e-01,
           8.35768692e-03,  1.71920583e-01,  7.69633651e-02,
           8.75835866e-02,  1.86722219e-01, -2.75155809e-02,
          -1.05050392e-02,  2.00979151e-02, -7.50234211e-03,
          -1.67125508e-01,  2.20861211e-02, -4.32664342e-03,
          -5.50425760e-02,  8.63447115e-02, -1.67248473e-01,
           1.38378460e-02,  1.11343339e-01, -1.99985191e-01,
           1.35348290e-01,  1.56460218e-02,  2.73892656e-04,
          -6.41771033e-02,  2.57192627e-02, -9.93981138e-02,
           8.97653773e-03,  1.91183090e-01, -2.82200336e-01,
           2.23059848e-01,  1.75120562e-01, -7.82503486e-02,
           1.47400096e-01,  4.67997603e-02,  7.76805580e-02,
           1.79661531e-02, -5.38391508e-02, -1.54771596e-01,
          -9.99689624e-02, -1.09263457e-01, -9.25640911e-02,
           1.83300804e-02,  8.41395408e-02]],
 
        [[-1.50231764e-01,  5.30236512e-02,  5.80971278e-02,
          -6.91052619e-03, -6.63885847e-02, -8.69466662e-02,
          -1.51826143e-02, -5.16197905e-02,  2.19310135e-01,
          -8.07677209e-02,  1.71911135e-01, -3.65424380e-02,
          -1.77088380e-01, -9.78112444e-02, -1.38332583e-02,
           8.34669024e-02, -1.31156802e-01, -1.49645716e-01,
          -3.05147469e-02, -1.17407627e-01,  1.71565767e-02,
           9.20448918e-03, -6.46030009e-02, -2.28046551e-02,
          -1.94293335e-01, -2.80386955e-01, -7.64302760e-02,
          -8.90514404e-02,  1.17872708e-01, -9.60179269e-02,
          -3.07646766e-02,  3.37364674e-02, -1.90276399e-01,
          -1.05832189e-01,  6.49234205e-02,  2.19782099e-01,
          -1.96797457e-02,  1.40418569e-02,  1.81732520e-01,
          -3.28570083e-02, -7.66380355e-02,  6.89617405e-03,
           4.78702188e-02,  2.45228872e-01,  1.41428009e-01,
           1.00809440e-01,  3.73133272e-03, -1.03467189e-01,
           8.70409757e-02, -2.12297142e-01,  9.47272182e-02,
           1.90620258e-01,  1.18681826e-01,  3.31691504e-02,
           1.67793304e-01, -2.18925700e-01, -9.66489222e-03,
           1.24859490e-01, -1.71614006e-01,  1.37775704e-01,
           8.33617598e-02,  1.09298751e-02, -4.55547757e-02,
          -2.22153030e-02,  1.64980054e-01,  1.37728015e-02,
          -9.32593867e-02, -7.81709999e-02,  2.22985357e-01,
          -1.69061244e-01,  4.10387591e-02,  4.30300683e-02,
          -1.11437151e-02, -1.98694319e-01, -2.07214892e-01,
           5.36098704e-02,  3.90068620e-01,  1.62774995e-01,
          -1.60267770e-01,  7.80781955e-02, -5.54403551e-02,
          -9.31668729e-02,  7.10664839e-02, -1.76445842e-02,
          -9.73844975e-02, -3.38197052e-02, -1.21390782e-01,
           4.05607447e-02,  1.57834575e-01,  6.25553131e-02,
           1.10172994e-01,  1.51440471e-01, -1.40509475e-02,
           3.16431560e-02, -2.47017704e-02, -3.98907140e-02,
          -1.65499881e-01,  3.11357491e-02, -5.87871447e-02,
          -4.44657058e-02,  1.02798469e-01, -1.55324146e-01,
           4.02739719e-02,  1.22631051e-01, -1.83685839e-01,
           1.04981773e-01, -6.72103511e-03, -2.01395378e-02,
          -1.53558785e-02,  5.07285669e-02, -9.66893956e-02,
          -1.21531086e-02,  2.01398820e-01, -2.65820712e-01,
           2.13555843e-01,  1.77817732e-01, -6.56121820e-02,
           1.58264607e-01,  8.97071287e-02,  9.25853327e-02,
           6.48394227e-02, -1.72733609e-02, -1.74576581e-01,
          -6.79302812e-02, -1.20070800e-01, -1.09205380e-01,
           2.45773457e-02,  9.11332145e-02]],
 
        [[-1.62274405e-01,  3.15038860e-02,  6.44017309e-02,
           3.45326737e-02, -1.05685055e-01, -1.77183170e-02,
          -8.56796950e-02, -7.91971534e-02,  1.71855256e-01,
          -1.71298254e-02,  1.86888188e-01,  3.59892212e-02,
          -1.92580983e-01, -6.18249550e-02,  1.21358195e-02,
           6.60665333e-02, -1.40805155e-01, -8.28307271e-02,
          -5.42851612e-02, -1.11442827e-01, -6.72461838e-03,
           1.96444243e-02,  2.98103131e-02,  6.19128272e-02,
          -1.93395317e-01, -2.87468702e-01, -8.87314901e-02,
          -1.30469680e-01,  6.98416680e-02, -1.32677779e-01,
           5.21699619e-03,  2.61115953e-02, -1.66991830e-01,
          -5.70339113e-02,  6.47078753e-02,  1.88027576e-01,
          -9.21493247e-02, -1.49603449e-02,  2.01233804e-01,
          -8.49104673e-02, -1.06238969e-01, -3.60001624e-02,
          -2.23363750e-03,  2.17491835e-01,  1.87389106e-01,
           1.04524858e-01,  5.11063896e-02, -6.64142743e-02,
           1.51605263e-01, -2.12667212e-01,  1.45079419e-01,
           1.72637925e-01,  6.61674738e-02,  3.34243253e-02,
           1.31693542e-01, -2.69493669e-01, -4.82268780e-02,
           2.30443150e-01, -8.99494663e-02,  1.42259493e-01,
           3.80099751e-03, -7.53545314e-02, -7.12354667e-03,
          -2.95820814e-02,  1.53193980e-01,  5.97309470e-02,
          -1.01371743e-01, -9.97453034e-02,  1.79987788e-01,
          -1.37784496e-01,  4.48415950e-02,  1.53983220e-01,
          -1.05956972e-01, -2.62854129e-01, -2.18802154e-01,
           4.18419279e-02,  4.67299223e-01,  1.23464331e-01,
          -1.62302554e-01,  3.13426740e-03, -6.86671678e-03,
          -6.07644059e-02,  4.79412451e-02,  8.40777308e-02,
          -6.54070973e-02, -4.18782346e-02, -1.13178916e-01,
           5.20941988e-02,  1.85022369e-01,  5.36964908e-02,
           3.61735113e-02,  1.85169518e-01, -1.91164780e-02,
           6.12748265e-02,  5.99459792e-03, -2.01658588e-02,
          -1.01727784e-01,  4.70405584e-03, -5.25830835e-02,
          -4.94561940e-02,  4.53589484e-02, -7.16509372e-02,
           2.04778500e-02,  5.09201735e-02, -1.25631809e-01,
           1.64057955e-01,  9.62968543e-03,  4.30290811e-02,
          -5.18420413e-02, -2.88595539e-02, -9.53822657e-02,
           3.55528444e-02,  2.59569615e-01, -2.95394242e-01,
           2.28176743e-01,  1.54641658e-01, -7.78511958e-03,
           2.09660888e-01,  2.91666016e-02,  9.74472538e-02,
           3.11672874e-02, -3.97840291e-02, -1.92549929e-01,
           5.36589068e-04, -2.17817314e-02, -1.05434239e-01,
           5.98730482e-02,  4.11710367e-02]]]),
 array([[[-1.68740377e-02,  1.52078941e-01,  8.62133503e-02,
           3.47440667e-03, -7.50775635e-02,  8.29034671e-02,
          -5.12160733e-02, -9.60651636e-02,  5.18606864e-02,
           4.61538620e-02,  2.11039424e-01, -7.04053193e-02,
          -2.30026633e-01, -2.06287913e-02,  4.42361459e-02,
           1.13250390e-01, -1.38955295e-01, -7.81948566e-02,
          -1.18520640e-01,  3.08102742e-03, -5.88674992e-02,
           3.52515951e-02,  1.02329694e-01, -3.15367128e-03,
          -1.09225258e-01, -2.74011433e-01, -7.80899003e-02,
          -9.12662745e-02,  1.24638416e-01, -8.57445747e-02,
          -3.88496295e-02, -1.19581092e-02, -1.75278068e-01,
           7.70506728e-03,  7.80697837e-02,  9.88397971e-02,
          -7.57867396e-02, -8.06069449e-02,  2.28473604e-01,
          -2.36921087e-02, -1.76744461e-01,  3.78885008e-02,
           8.70054811e-02,  1.42934516e-01,  2.38303959e-01,
           6.11009710e-02,  4.36121263e-02, -3.50601189e-02,
           6.64255023e-02, -2.49209940e-01,  1.57682329e-01,
           1.21789858e-01,  1.16867483e-01,  8.45996961e-02,
           5.76233957e-03, -1.76971704e-01, -4.91473451e-02,
           1.56083614e-01, -1.41750157e-01,  7.08352476e-02,
           9.80508104e-02, -8.59858245e-02, -8.23098868e-02,
          -1.59299485e-02,  1.51134863e-01,  1.43824801e-01,
          -1.24966606e-01, -1.75318450e-01,  1.13390550e-01,
          -1.68713510e-01, -3.53813954e-02,  1.21039249e-01,
          -8.95563290e-02, -1.01484008e-01, -2.75068283e-01,
           5.46966009e-02,  4.39682692e-01,  3.67938466e-02,
          -1.56368658e-01, -1.16297044e-02, -1.52784062e-03,
          -2.47500669e-02, -1.95040870e-02,  1.20051503e-01,
          -6.90754429e-02, -8.28582197e-02, -4.97369617e-02,
           2.63527036e-05,  1.96313396e-01, -6.30125403e-02,
           4.69858525e-03,  1.56594262e-01, -1.63011625e-02,
           5.98538369e-02, -2.65194569e-04,  6.69567063e-02,
           2.51362212e-02, -5.55414632e-02, -2.93561518e-02,
           2.84286365e-02, -4.83711883e-02, -9.81986448e-02,
          -3.45682539e-02,  7.68979266e-02, -1.98029101e-01,
           1.53635189e-01,  7.00153364e-03, -3.65675725e-02,
           7.30676875e-02, -1.04091987e-02, -5.18539827e-03,
          -2.50395797e-02,  2.01758057e-01, -3.52356672e-01,
           1.77500680e-01,  1.84066370e-01, -4.49734628e-02,
           8.69778767e-02,  3.74429524e-02,  1.81517109e-01,
           7.69926533e-02,  5.22192307e-02, -1.70259267e-01,
          -1.13618262e-01, -1.40291126e-02, -4.68849167e-02,
          -3.22203897e-02,  5.76205775e-02]],
 
        [[-2.49804370e-02,  1.70671448e-01,  3.95690724e-02,
          -3.51276388e-03, -1.98742189e-02,  7.46497139e-02,
          -2.03474741e-02, -1.11103363e-01,  1.02668263e-01,
           2.93022245e-02,  2.07146153e-01,  3.29615586e-02,
          -2.63025105e-01, -2.46658288e-02,  3.71336676e-02,
           8.23173597e-02, -1.64193496e-01, -9.91019532e-02,
          -1.28058136e-01, -2.77458709e-02, -3.55885737e-02,
           8.64468515e-02,  6.67003468e-02, -4.39326577e-02,
          -1.09597728e-01, -2.84543842e-01, -7.25509301e-02,
          -8.68509933e-02,  1.06886305e-01, -1.30941182e-01,
          -9.13744885e-03,  4.62066382e-04, -1.28790632e-01,
           2.69941334e-02,  8.28079656e-02,  5.13078235e-02,
          -5.22269905e-02, -4.96672578e-02,  2.61806935e-01,
           6.24357723e-02, -2.08110198e-01,  5.77822179e-02,
           8.79181474e-02,  2.49593109e-01,  2.41651326e-01,
          -8.27671867e-03, -1.22608151e-02, -7.38239959e-02,
           8.41363668e-02, -2.08070427e-01,  1.60519928e-01,
           1.58879861e-01,  1.78740799e-01,  1.20273851e-01,
          -4.65768203e-03, -2.10287139e-01, -4.37513739e-02,
           1.08855076e-01, -1.95248336e-01,  5.24971373e-02,
           1.16677418e-01, -1.18925139e-01, -8.58063847e-02,
           1.45739652e-02,  1.05634734e-01,  1.13258652e-01,
          -1.43801495e-01, -1.55666292e-01,  6.84999675e-02,
          -1.38900787e-01, -2.64124889e-02,  9.55415145e-02,
          -1.27598137e-01, -1.43201396e-01, -2.41060451e-01,
           6.54740036e-02,  3.65032971e-01,  4.02122661e-02,
          -1.57019958e-01, -4.69299685e-03, -5.40541038e-02,
          -3.91884111e-02, -9.02013388e-03,  9.22192931e-02,
          -1.14169739e-01, -6.25471398e-02, -7.63412844e-03,
           5.29423654e-02,  1.69518501e-01, -2.44914368e-02,
          -4.37655076e-02,  1.66987330e-01, -3.33075225e-02,
           4.13864255e-02,  1.90281402e-02,  9.10777077e-02,
           2.46177800e-03, -4.55477871e-02, -6.55916557e-02,
          -3.10473237e-03, -4.02890295e-02, -1.70472056e-01,
          -2.12542713e-04,  7.25972354e-02, -2.65269011e-01,
           1.94183111e-01,  8.99361670e-02, -2.56836135e-02,
           9.89286229e-02, -2.27259118e-02, -2.12507583e-02,
          -1.31608464e-03,  2.12979823e-01, -3.51205587e-01,
           2.74906904e-01,  2.04230517e-01,  1.13111669e-02,
           1.17748439e-01,  4.00286205e-02,  1.06981196e-01,
           2.57537849e-02,  6.92378357e-03, -1.54393032e-01,
          -6.81875497e-02,  3.07280570e-05, -6.17604423e-03,
           1.25430766e-02,  3.37549895e-02]],
 
        [[ 3.33601981e-02,  2.18950808e-01,  5.25589399e-02,
          -6.06435016e-02, -8.43613148e-02,  7.20153004e-02,
          -6.08830974e-02, -8.34409371e-02,  9.67382044e-02,
          -3.27746384e-04,  2.91555285e-01, -4.84346934e-02,
          -2.59748727e-01, -6.66559637e-02,  3.30047011e-02,
           1.45614624e-01, -2.04137906e-01, -1.10366166e-01,
          -1.42498747e-01, -3.80640477e-03, -1.71378646e-02,
           5.47722988e-02,  6.41267151e-02,  3.91335320e-03,
          -8.57527778e-02, -2.98490942e-01, -5.11459038e-02,
          -1.01354338e-01,  1.27257884e-01, -1.28999814e-01,
          -4.14374061e-02,  2.56892070e-02, -1.13893583e-01,
          -2.45535634e-02,  6.04319125e-02,  6.74173683e-02,
          -9.40101370e-02, -6.67680278e-02,  1.88137412e-01,
           1.32872257e-03, -1.82188556e-01,  4.39332426e-02,
           4.49893773e-02,  2.36567542e-01,  2.72193104e-01,
           1.17838997e-02,  3.05325892e-02, -7.49155506e-02,
           3.77691165e-02, -2.66298920e-01,  1.48846105e-01,
           1.64895594e-01,  1.55318990e-01,  1.38803110e-01,
           1.64481476e-02, -1.58437371e-01,  1.97825730e-02,
           1.52800277e-01, -1.72297224e-01,  8.14515352e-02,
           1.22895420e-01, -1.38855070e-01, -4.93918136e-02,
           1.82603858e-02,  1.62638202e-01,  1.25332266e-01,
          -1.04849547e-01, -1.97150543e-01,  5.53290471e-02,
          -1.32151425e-01, -9.59372669e-02,  1.17293313e-01,
          -1.40096560e-01, -9.66465995e-02, -2.62960464e-01,
           3.64195369e-02,  3.95120800e-01,  2.55586170e-02,
          -1.97585553e-01, -2.96364930e-02, -1.63999517e-02,
          -4.40649725e-02,  1.55332964e-02,  6.92601651e-02,
          -1.09604046e-01, -1.56740874e-01, -1.17389277e-01,
           3.95389833e-02,  1.88643590e-01, -1.13158882e-01,
          -8.29163101e-03,  1.95588186e-01, -3.58534269e-02,
          -8.23678449e-04,  4.84100729e-02,  1.09540187e-01,
          -3.94673832e-03,  1.27359228e-02, -1.72595084e-02,
          -2.12953091e-02,  6.26803562e-02, -1.98052153e-01,
          -6.99584559e-02,  7.20234066e-02, -2.17735857e-01,
           1.60721123e-01, -1.33986981e-03,  1.67240351e-02,
           1.30067334e-01, -5.92296720e-02, -1.77724455e-02,
          -4.66314182e-02,  2.72649646e-01, -2.63336450e-01,
           2.49853805e-01,  2.26347536e-01,  2.04152986e-02,
           6.42477721e-02,  3.84325832e-02,  1.51295438e-01,
           6.71947282e-03, -1.82412043e-02, -1.52144179e-01,
          -6.57561570e-02, -4.76292893e-03, -1.88203622e-02,
          -3.31684798e-02,  2.50659473e-02]],
 
        [[ 2.82088853e-03,  1.88540086e-01,  1.68683734e-02,
          -6.15225211e-02, -6.66730106e-02,  9.25483927e-02,
           3.60094849e-03, -5.96660934e-02,  1.67936683e-01,
           5.15804440e-02,  2.56727725e-01, -3.05743832e-02,
          -2.75632173e-01, -9.82266143e-02,  4.73604612e-02,
           1.32066280e-01, -1.86928630e-01, -1.10467285e-01,
          -1.12709492e-01,  7.98108894e-03, -4.31619100e-02,
           6.35776296e-02,  6.79053143e-02,  1.44015867e-02,
          -8.84011164e-02, -2.98023641e-01, -3.90912741e-02,
          -1.25116169e-01,  9.76984650e-02, -9.94135663e-02,
           3.06001399e-03, -7.61403609e-03, -1.88553363e-01,
          -1.57480519e-02,  1.00236654e-01,  7.26338178e-02,
          -9.02482495e-02, -5.35438582e-02,  2.11272717e-01,
           1.75018534e-02, -2.12516204e-01,  1.55753875e-03,
           4.49219495e-02,  2.19748080e-01,  1.73106432e-01,
           4.12785672e-02,  5.25815338e-02, -6.54551387e-02,
           6.16361424e-02, -2.10121647e-01,  1.38409883e-01,
           1.92241967e-01,  1.80396318e-01,  5.53400852e-02,
           2.47791149e-02, -2.10880712e-01, -5.11872470e-02,
           1.33346096e-01, -1.77311331e-01,  7.78129473e-02,
           1.01757452e-01, -4.89850864e-02, -7.23917037e-02,
          -3.58456001e-02,  1.46720067e-01,  8.36935937e-02,
          -1.50431842e-01, -1.78618789e-01,  1.38929337e-01,
          -1.36039600e-01, -4.11997065e-02,  1.43187419e-01,
          -1.19545117e-01, -1.70583084e-01, -2.55052835e-01,
           1.76979043e-02,  4.10075754e-01,  1.73812360e-02,
          -1.80650592e-01, -5.94558157e-02, -6.30004108e-02,
          -2.35346705e-02, -6.34292066e-02,  1.02112904e-01,
          -8.55509266e-02, -4.29085605e-02, -7.77176172e-02,
           1.18833035e-02,  2.08374113e-01, -9.88899767e-02,
          -4.22141049e-03,  1.64182067e-01, -3.29365134e-02,
          -2.23313347e-02, -3.83415073e-02,  5.85192628e-02,
           3.04613076e-02, -6.51986338e-03, -3.01447697e-02,
           1.43439416e-02, -2.54644640e-02, -1.97629541e-01,
          -6.60173446e-02,  5.97969070e-02, -2.76524663e-01,
           1.50484443e-01,  6.61896765e-02, -5.83832599e-02,
           2.87721884e-02,  9.68062668e-04, -3.71711180e-02,
          -2.21348181e-02,  2.51920044e-01, -3.40805888e-01,
           2.91597039e-01,  2.26792172e-01,  1.19546121e-02,
           1.11737035e-01, -5.84540702e-03,  1.46952957e-01,
           3.79731879e-02, -5.13361618e-02, -1.33946911e-01,
          -1.59345180e-01, -5.29028401e-02, -2.98120938e-02,
          -1.22097181e-02,  2.81007364e-02]]])]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the data, you see a list of multiple arrays, what you have to do is you convert each one of them to DataFrame.
So to convert one of them to DataFrame, you need to use the nested array `pd.DataFrame(arrays_list[0][0])`
than concat them all with loop and concat.

```
from numpy import array
arrays_list = [array([[[-1.36013642e-01,  1.59766637e-02,  4.49674837e-02,...,
          -1.22097181e-02,  2.81007364e-02]]])]
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
for i in  range(len(arrays_list)):
    for j in range(len(arrays_list[i])):
        df = pd.concat([df , pd.DataFrame(arrays_list[i][j]) ]).reset_index(drop=True)
df
```

[image: ![enter image description here]

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Thank you. Can you please clarify what 'a' represents in the list comprehension?

Comment: a is your array list :)

Comment: Thanks. But for some reason, it kept on repeating the same first array for every rows in the dataframe. Do you know any reason for it?

Comment: yes, I edited that, the for did not change the index, now it does.
`df = pd.concat([pd.DataFrame(a[i][0]) for i in range(len(a))]).reset_index(drop=False)
df`

Comment: Thank you. Life saver. Any brief comment on how the list comprehension worked the way it worked?

Comment: sure, at first I tried what you probably tried `pd.DataFrame(a)`, and got an error. then I tried `pd.DataFrame(a[0])` and got an error so I looked at the `a[0]` and saw that it is 3 brackets "[[[" , and df - rows need 2 brackets so `df(a[0][0])`

Comment: Hey Ran, I hope you are there. I realised today that the work you showed me yesterday was not what I wanted to do. I wanted to transform each individual array, meaning numbers inside each [[..]] into rows in dataframe. I tried alot of methods but it didn't work

Comment: Hi, Im not sure that I understand what you mean can you give me an example?

Comment: Sure.I will try my best. If you look at the list of numbers I posted above yesterday, 128 numbers are between [[..]] two big brackets. Right? and then another 128 numbers are between [[..]]. I wanted numbers in each double big brackets into rows. And another numbers between each [[..]] into another rows in dataframe. Did you get it? Or should I make a new comment below?

Comment: so if you look at above example I want numbers from(check first number in first array) (-1.36013642e-01) to (7.31237382e-02) into one row of dataframe. so on and so forth

Comment: so, instead of multiple rows, you want one df of 128, and another one for the second?
df1.shape(1,128) df2.shape(1,128)

Comment: No no. I want multiple rows. I want one df but one rows with 128 value and another one with another 128 values

Comment: So from -1.36013642e-01 to 7.31237382e-02 I want it in one row in dataframe

Comment: it's exactly my answer   
you should get one df  -   
row1: -0.136014 to 0.073124  
row2: -0.016874 to 0.057621

Comment: I see a bug there .reset_index(drop=True) and not false

Comment: Hi. I checked it again but it takes the whole array and not the numbers between [[..]] in each rows in dataframe. Can you please check again

Comment: sure, let me check :)

Comment: I think we have a misunderstanding. What I wanted was -1.36013642e-01 to 7.31237382e-02 in one row and -1.37894586e-01 to 8.41395408e-02 in another row and so on

Comment: Here, my apology, I didn't see that the data contained more than two rows.

Comment: I recommend on the playlist of Data School by Kevin Markham on pandas, It's a good start for beginners. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yzIMircGU5I&list=PL5-da3qGB5ICCsgW1MxlZ0Hq8LL5U3u9y

Answer (score 1):

**I want to convert each arrays in the nested arrays as data frame rows.**

What I get from your question is you each array is going to be your row in df:

```
# this is your nested array
nestedarrays=[np.zeros(shape=(1, 1, 20)) for i in range(24)] 

processedarrays=[nestedarray[0][0] for nestedarray in nestedarrays] 

df=pd.DataFrame(processedarrays)

df.head()

     0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19
0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
1  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
2  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
3  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
4  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0  0.0
```